# Export sqoop eval results into a comma delimited output

Tags: bash, shell, sqoop

I am running a sqoop eval code which produces output in a pipe separated format. I would like to have it in a comma format and remove the extra formatting so that I can store it in variable and can use somewhere else.

Below is the code:

`sqoop eval -Dmapreduce.job.queuename=comres $PASS_STRING --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://XXXX:1433;DatabaseName=XXXX' --query "select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name='MOT_BAJA' AND TABLE_CATALOG='EEEE'"`

This is what is showing right now:

```
------------------------
| column_name          |
------------------------
| TB_CODIGO            |
| TB_ELEMENT           |
| TB_INGLES            |
| TB_IMSS              |
| TB_NUMERO            |
| TB_TEXTO             |
| LLAVE                |
------------------------
```

I want it like this:

```
TB_CODIGO,TB_ELEMENT,TB_INGLES,TB_IMSS,TB_NUMERO,TB_TEXTO,LLAVE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe use awk:

```
your_command | awk 'NR > 3 && NF==3 {printf "%s%s", (printed ? "," : ""), $2; printed++}'
```

Explanation:

`NR > 3 && NF == 3`: if the Number of Row (NR) we are currently processing is greater than 3, and the Number of Fields (NF) for this row is 3, then go ahead and process the row using the code in `{ ... }`.

`printed`: we keep in this variable the number of fields we have printed by far.

`(printed ? "," : "")`: if have printed at least one field by far, this evaluates to ",". Else it evaluates to an empty string "".

`printf "%s%s", (printed ? "," : ""), $2`: , print a "," if we have already printed a field before. Then print the second word of the current row.

Comment: The output for above is below: column_name,TB_CODIGO,TB_ELEMENT,TB_INGLES,TB_IMSS,TB_NUMERO,TB_TEXTO,LLAVE. I don't want 'column_name' in this.

Comment: This should not happen, because of 'NR > 3' which only processes lines after the 3rd line. Maybe a copy paste error?

Comment: getting same output only. No copy paste errors. column_name,TB_CODIGO,TB_ELEMENT,TB_INGLES,TB_IMSS,TB_NUMERO,TB_TEXTO,LLAVE.

Comment: Maybe your command prints some empty lines before the text you pasted above? Then you may need to adjust `NR > 3`. Because based on the output you gave, the awk script works http://jdoodle.com/a/1jJ5